# Maple can't solve sample code

Tags: maple

I couldn't get Maple to solve this sample function at [its own documentation](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=rsolve):

```
rsolve({y(n)=ny(n−1),y(0)=1},y)
```

The output in the documentation is `Gamma(n+1)`. But when I executed the code, Maple only returns

```
{y(0) = 1, y(n) = ny(n-1)}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put multiplication there. Now `ny` is seen as a variable, and not as `n*y`. If you insert the mulitplication or a space, then the output is indeed `Gamma(n+1)`